# WCAG error: broken rule regarding label for email input (What am I missing?)

Tags: html, forms, wcag

I keep getting an error in multiple accessibility tests stating that my form doesn't have a label. I added the `for="EMAIL"` for the label. Am I missing something?

```
<p>
    <label for="EMAIL">Email address: </label>
    <input type="email" name="EMAIL" placeholder="Your email address" required />
</p>

<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Sign up" name="signup"/>
</p>
```

Comment: @trevorp Please do not [change other peoples' code styles](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20742325). If code formatting is missing altogether, you can add it as you please, but changing four spaces to two, etc., is not an OK edit. Also, do not insert two spaces after periods/fullstops; that is a vestigial practice from the typewriter days; web browsers have never displayed the additional space on web pages anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `for` attribute on the `<label>` object is designed to be used with an **`id`** attribute.

Try:

```
<input type="email" name="EMAIL" id="EMAIL" placeholder="Your email address" required />
```